# File image can't display in production server laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, production-environment

I have a form that contains an image upload

On my local, I can upload and photo files can be displayed

On my production server, I can upload, but photo file can`t be displayed (Page Not Found)

I have checked that the file has been successfully uploaded

My project was using Laravel 5.1.46

File location on my local :

```
xampp\htdocs\MyProject\public\files\images\myImages.jpg
```

File location on my production server :

```
var\www\MyProject\public\files\images\myImages.jpg
```

filesystems.php :

```
'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],
```

form.blade.php :

```
<div class="form-body">
    {!! Form::suitFileBrowser("image", 'Background', $model->image, ['info' => 'Image must be in JPG/JPEG format']) !!}
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `asset` function for referencing to the file?

Comment: add `'url' => env('APP_URL')` this in your filesystem.php then you will be get image url by `Storage::disk('local')->url($ImgaePath)`

Comment: What kind of asset function? I'm new in laravel and i didn't create the project from the beginning

Comment: what is the path of your url?

Comment: I've added the url in filesystem.php but the file image still doesn't display. Is there any more settings?

Comment: On my local : http://localhost:8000/files/images/myImages.jpg
On my production server : https://MyProject.com/files/images/myImages.jpg

Comment: Please post the blade where in you're addressing to file

Comment: @isvadhaputri what server your using ? your url seems correct to me

Comment: i use apache web server

Comment: then `var\www\MyProject\public\files\images\myImages.jpg` it can be access by `MyProject.com/files/images/myImages.jpg` check in server location may be there is image is not uploaded

Comment: I have checked that the file has been successfully uploaded

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the blade file:

```
{{ URL::to('/') }}/files/images/myImages.jpg
```

Another way to use `public_path()`

it will find the public folder:

```
<img src=public_path().'files/images/myImages.jpg' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answers make sure your folder has at-least read permission to access the images.